# How to properly add webapps to unity on 13.10

Tags: unity, 13.10, chromium, webapps

I'm new to ubuntu, and one of the features that made the change from windows was the integrated webapps.

I installed ubuntu 13.10, installed the unity-webapps-service and the unity-chromium-extension via terminal. Once I opened Gmail, facebook, google docs, etc... they all offered me to install it on ubuntu. But all I get is the icon on the applications menu, there's no integration with the top bar or the HUD.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

That could be possible and enabled if you have setup your account here. I mean in the system settings you will find online accounts like mentioned in the below image. if you set your account over here then you'll get what you wanted.

[image]

Comment: I did add those accounts before trying to add the webapps

Comment: Then have you installed them when the prompt came up in the browser ?

Comment: Yes, I did, and the only one that integrated with unity is twitter, the others are just links that open a separate window